# Load website in div using curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl to retrieve an external website and display it in a div...

```
    function Get_Domain_Contents($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;   
}
```

but how do I get it to return the css and images of that webpage too? Right now it just returns everything except the images and css. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is much easier with an `<iframe>`. Is there any reason why you can't use one?

Comment: It works just fine in a div for me. I just need the images and css to load as well

Comment: Mirroring someone else's content without permission is a copyright violation.

Comment: You will have to do an additional curl request for each image and for the css files on the page. every browser does this automatically for you. You will also have to parse the html document for the urls of those images and css files... ;-)

Comment: the site is likely using relative URLs for their CSS and images, which resolve to *your* server instead of the original server once you load it with `curl`. Like @JamWaffles said, it's much easier to do this with an `<iframe>`; otherwise you'll have to parse the HTML and rewrite the URLS yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://example.com';

$html = Get_Domain_Contents($url);

$html = "<base href='{$url}' />" . $html;

echo $html;
```

Comment: This was the best one for me so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than download all these extra files, you could parse the content that you downloaded and modify any relative URLs to make them absolute URLs.  You'd be using them in place and the CSS and images would be included in the rendered code.  You could use something like the [PHP simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to make parsing part of the task easier.